# chartjs + Angular6 is not showing charts or any error

Tags: angular, canvas, chart.js

I m trying to implement chart.js in angular, have written a simple code to display chart on html, but there is not output on the page, also there are no errors. I m not getting where is the issue and why displaying chart is getting failed.
[slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularchartjs) url for reference

Code that I m trying in component:

```
this.chart1 = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['solid', 'liquid', 'unknown'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'test',
            data: [
              100, 200, 300
            ],
            backgroundColor: ['#0074D9', '#2ECC40', '#FF4136']
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: 'Color test'
        },
        legend: {
          position: 'left',
          display: true,
          fullWidth: true,
          labels: {
            fontSize: 11
          }
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true
          }]
        }
      }
    });
```

Please help me to understand where I m getting failed, Thanks

Comment: This answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43151705/8365253

Comment: @HariniP Thanks for response, I think I have tried that already and that has not worked for me

Comment: @HariniP have any idea what is wrong in the given code, as i m not getting any error to trace issue

Comment: did you install @types/chart.js

Comment: @yer Thanks yer, updated with @types/chart.js same problem no error, no output

Comment: @Vino Stackblitz url isn't updated?

Comment: @User3250 updated url check now

Comment: Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts, I think there wasn't any problem with your code. Did you try it locally?

Comment: @WazzaEl that was the first link which i got working with chartjs, but when i used the given code in it did'nt worked, plus I have also tried different ways which I got on some blog articles, but all the methods are not working at my side for some reasons,

Comment: I found the solution. Wrap your `<canvas>` with `<div>`, like this: `<div><canvas id="canvas"></canvas><div>`. For ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084296/how-to-implement-chart-js-in-angular2.

Comment: @WazzaEl Thanks, wrapping it into div is showing chart, ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Code in component is correct, issue was in html
wrapping the `<canvas>` tag inside `<div>` has solved the issue as said in comment by @Quan Vo

Example:

```
<div><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>
```

Why `<canvas>` tag should be inside `<div>` tag, for this one can refer [this article](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/)

In Short:

The HTML5 Canvas element is an HTML tag similar to the `<div>`, `<a>`, or `<table>` tag, with the exception that its contents are rendered with JavaScript.  In order to leverage the HTML5 Canvas, we'll need to place the canvas tag somewhere inside the HTML document, access the canvas tag with JavaScript, create a context, and then utilize the HTML5 Canvas API to draw visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem and what was wrong was just the import, I was using "import { Chart } from "chart.js" " and I saw another way to import and that in my case solved it. It was like this, "import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'. If I wanted to know more about it, I saw this solution in this link: https://www.angularfix.com/2021/10/chart-js-graph-not-showing-on-canvas.html